# Merge JSON Object arrays and sort with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object with 12 arrays. Different regions of countries. I'm trying to merge this array into select dropdown menu. The JSON looks like this:

```
"latinamerica": [
        "Argentina",
        "Bolivia",
        "Brazil",
        "Chile",
        "Colombia",
        "Ecuador",
        "Paraguay",
        "Peru"
    ],
    "korea": ["South Korea"]
```

Then I call in the JSON with:

```
    $.getJSON('js/countries.json', function(data) {

  var items = [];      

  items[0] = '<option value="0">Country</option>';

  $.each(data['latinamerica'], function(key, val) {
    items.push('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ val +'</option>');
  });
});
```

Doing this for every array in the Object. Problem is I want to merge all these arrays, sort them alphabetically but still maintain what region they are associated with. So essentially I would have a dropdown of all the countries and the HTML would look like:

```
<option value="latinamerica">Argentina</option>
<option value="europe">Austria</option>
```

I've tried doing concat but then I lose my array names. Suggestions? TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically need a different "model" to generate that "view":

```
var countries = [];
for (var region in data) {
  for (var i = 0, l = data[region].length; i < l; ++i) {  
    countries.push({ country: data[region][i], region: region });
  }
}
```

Then you sort it:

```
countries.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.country < b.country) return -1;
  if (a.country > b.country) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

And then you use it:

```
var items = [];      

items.push('<option value="0">Country</option>');
for (var i = 0, l = countries.length; i < l; ++i) {
  items.push('<option value="'+ countries[i].region +'">'+ countries[i].country +'</option>');
}
```

(NOTE: all this code is *untested*).

Comment: Note that `b.country - a.country` would also be possible in the sort function.

Comment: Excellent. I knew I needed to push them into their own array but was missing the multi-dimensional facet of things. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.innerHTML < b.innerHTML) return -1;
  else return 1;
});
```

Add the Country option after the sort.