# How to merge two array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have two array of objects like following:

```js
result = [{id:24, name:"xyz"}, {id:45,name:"tze"}]
moreDetails = [{id:24, name2:"hyi"}, {id:45, name2:"tikw"}]
```

I want a merged result of above like this

```js
mergedResult= [{id:24, name:"xyz", name2:"hyi"}, {id:45,name:"tze", name2:"tikw"}]
```

Please notice the merging is happening on `id`, which both of the arrays have.

I tried to follow this one [How to merge these arrays/json objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166651/how-to-merge-these-arrays-json-objects) and this one [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically?rq=1)

But, I think I got lost and my question might require a short and simple solution.

**EDIT**

I tried to simplify my example. In actual, both of above arrays just have `id` in common, they have more than name, name2. For example, sometime `result` array will have `id, name, name2, name3`  and `moreDetails` will have `id, name, name4` . I am trying to say, that I don't always know in ahead of time what both array will have except `id`. So, I cannot hard-code field names as some of the answers suggested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop, in this case extending one of the arrays' elements is better than creating another array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i].name2 = moreDetails[i].name2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9uchU/

In case that target elements have different indices:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var c = result[i],
        // filtering the second array based on the `id` 
        // of the current element 
        m = moreDetails.filter(function(elem) {
             return elem.id === c.id;
        })[0];
    c.name2 = m ? m.name2 : 'not defined';
}
```

Edit: Based on your last edit, as @Blender mentions, you can also use jQuery `$.extend()` utility function:

```
$.extend(result, moreDetails);
```

Comment: You could also do `$.extend(result[i], moreDetails[i])`

Comment: +1. I am going to try this. BTW, please see my edit in question.

Comment: I was gonna answer with @Blender's comment, you should make it as an answer. Also, I'm pretty sure you dont need [i] part, just $.extend(arr1, arr2);

Comment: @Blender `$.extend(result[i], moreDetails[i])` worked. If you won't post your comment as an answer, I will have to accept this one, many thanks!.

Comment: @TomFobear  it `$.extend(result, moreDetails)` without [i] didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    function findElement(arr, propName, propValue) {
      for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i][propName] == propValue){
          return arr[i];
        }
      }
    }

    var result = [{id:24, name:"xyz"}, {id:45,name:"tze"}];
    var moreDetails= [{id:24, name2:"hyi"}, {id:45, name2:"tikw"}];
    var mergedResult = result;

    for (var i = 0; i<result.length;i++ ) {
      //mergedResult[i].name2 = findElement(moreDetails, "id", result[i].id).name2
    $.extend(mergedResult[i],findElement(moreDetails, "id", result[i].id));
    } 

    mergedResult;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!, please see my edit in question. I provided more details.

Comment: Updated the example for you :)

Comment: thanks for detailed code example, I will give this post up vote as soon as I earn 15pts :)